# How to make slick iOS interfaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've been learning for 5 months now, and making my own app, and the hardest thing for me are custom UIViews, and just slick and nice custom iOS user interfaces with all the cool animations and stuff.

I'm more like "functionality guy", but I really want to provide my users a great experience, so can you refer me to some resources about this magic for me.

Here are some cool examples that for me are super hard to do in code:

-sliding a cell with a finger and revealing a underneath menu. Okay I know about the center property but how do I position stuff underneath the cell?

-Changing the `frame` property dynamically. I just can't position some buttons next to each other and that's it.

-making any kind of custom UI control. That's something like a dream for me. If I need something my only choice is going through GitHub for ready controls.

Little stuff like this, and because of this I prefer Interface Builder for anything related to UIViews.

So can you refer me to any resources, books, manuals and documentation?

I've already read the UIView official docs and gone through some examples. I've read a book about Core Graphics and UIView animation (not Core Animation), and gone through all examples, but it's still hard for me, so any other good books or anything like that?

Comment: These types of extra animations and beautiful interfaces don't necessarily equal a great useable interface. You can certainly make very useable interfaces without these types of customizations.

As far as learning how to make these types of interfaces, I would suggest you draw them out on paper and type to create a step by step list of the parts of the animations. Then come back to SO and post specific questions when you get stuck on a particular step :)

Comment: Also since you're obviously accustomed to searching github, go download some of the better ones and study their implementations. Look for common pieces in all of them as well as which pieces are wholly custom to that component. Try to pick them apart and recreate them yourself with perhaps different variables like timing and resistance to get a feel for why they made certain decisions.

Answer (score 3):

Well creating good user interfaces is not about putting in particular controls, it's about making the interface very usable for what the user wants to accomplish, and there is no magic formula for this.

There are some concepts you could keep in mind.  A good user interface should at least:

1. Make it clear what the user should do next.
2. Allow the user to accomplish this with a minimum of interaction.
3. Get out of the user's way when not needed.

If you look at the above, you may notice that too much focus on particular controls can actually lead to poor interfaces as some things are used for the flash factor and can become obnoxious.

With that said, there are some usability metrics that you could use as a rough guide, and that should help someone with a more functional mindset.  You can google those, but here's a page with some that should get you started:
http://www.measuringusability.com/blog/essential-metrics.php

A while ago, I read a book called "The Humane Interface" which I thought had some good ideas on UIs.  It's an older book, but I think much of what it had to say still rings true to this day.

Finally, go online and check out some web sites.  Heaven knows the web is the perfect medium for how NOT TO design a user interface.  Even big companies display shocking incompetence when designing what should be the most straight-forward of sites.  See what the bad sites are and why you dislike them.  See what the good sites are and why you like them.  Sure these are web sites, but they still require interactivity and are therefore relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Some answers:

> -sliding a cell with a finger and revealing a underneath menu. Okay I know about the center property but how do I position stuff underneath
>   the cell?

Use method `sendToBack()` to position a view under all other subviews.

> Changing the frame property dynamically. I just can't position some
>   buttons next to each other and that's it.

Use `setCenter()` to move views.

> Little stuff like this, and because of this I prefer Interface Builder
>   for anything related to UIViews.

For custom controls / view, you have to prefer programmed views.
Just look into the source code of such custom views and controls you mention from gitHub, then you get more ideas what and how to do.